# Wordpress - Custom taxonomy filter in theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, taxonomy

I want to edit the checkout, receipt and other pages in **Easy Digital Downloads** plugin. 
As their [documentation](http://docs.easydigitaldownloads.com/article/279-customizing-the-checkout-cart-template), I've copied that file in my current theme's folder/edd_templates/ 
Actually, I have **2 different categories** (workshop, software) and I'm looking for a way to show **different tables** for **checkout page for every single one** of these categories.
So, I've tried to use this :

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_per_page' => '-1',
    'post_type' => 'download',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'download_category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'workshop'
        )
)
);
$my_posts = get_posts( $args );
if ( $my_posts ) :
?>
// custom html table for first category goes here... //
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
$args1 = array(
'post_per_page' => '-1',
'post_type' => 'download',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'download_category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'software'
    )
)
);
$myy_posts = get_posts( $args1 );
if ( $myy_posts ) :
?>
// custom html table for second category goes here... //
<?php endif; ?>
```

But it shows both tables in checkout page, no matter in which category you are ... 
I think the problem is that I have told wordpress to show these html tables just IF there is something in those categories. Not to filter them...
How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this many way, one of i show you below,
First create template page for your desire page, like Checkout

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Checkout
 *
 */
```

then right Your code into custom template file.
next go admin dashboard then select your custom template Checkout.

[image]

that page will show your desire output.

Answer (score 0):

You're right on your last paragraph, you didn't put any filters. You need to get the categories of the products in the cart first.

```
<?php $cart_items = edd_get_cart_contents(); //get the contents in the cart
foreach ( $cart_items as $key => $item ): ?>

<?php 
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $item->ID, 'download_category' ); //get the categories of the items in the cart
foreach ( $terms as $term ) $categories[] = $term->slug; //form an array with those categories
```

Then you need to check if that category array has your terms

```
if ( in_array( 'workshop', $categories ) ) {
// custom html table for first category goes here... //
}elseif ( in_array( 'software', $categories ) ){
// custom html table for second category goes here... //
else {
// custom html table for regular downloads goes here... //
}
```